# Mysql LOAD INFILE not uploading data into database table

Tags: php, mysqli, load-data-infile

I've been spending hours today just to try to figure out why I'm unable to upload data from a csv file into a database table with the LOAD INFILE straight from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). Now I have seen around here that my problem could have been the `LINES TERMINATED BY` so I diligitently tried them all `\n` `\r` and `\r\n`. Still nothing here. I'm scratching my dog's head. Have no idea.

Looking into the console under `Network` -> `Params`, everything appears okay returning the csv file as follow :

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mydata_2018.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
first_name,last_name,gender
John,Doe,Male
```

This suggests that everything is working fine on that end. But still, nothing gets inserted nor do I receive any error data. Any suggestion?

This is the code

```
if(isset( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']){

    //post variable
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    //set path
    $path = '../csv/';

    //upload files in folder
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path .$_FILES['file']['name']);

    //upload csv
    $stmt_user = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path.$filename'
                            INTO TABLE users
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                            IGNORE 1 LINES
                            (first_name,last_name,gender)";
     $resultstmt_user = $conn->query($stmt_user); 
     var_dump($resultstmt_user)//returns bool(false)
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error reported?

Comment: Did you look in the error log

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Excuse my perfect ignorance... you mean where?

Comment: On the screen? In the PHP Error log? In the Apache error log?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Ha the screen. Someone has a sense of humor. I didn't find anything in the logs.

Comment: You would be surprised how unfunny _the screen_ actually is. :)

Comment: I see you are not looking for error so. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: lol. Well, I should have thought about this. I was able to solve the problem. The file could not be found with the way I wrote it previously. Now it works like this `'csv/$filename'` instead of `$path.$filename`. Now don't know what you want to do... you have so many credits you would think you created the word itself. But anyway thanks :)

Comment: Great, solving it yourself is so much better, you wont make that mistake again or if you do you will know what to look for. :) :)